# Using library defined function in .Rprofile

Tags: r

I have a library `foo` that defines a function `bar` that I would like to use as a custom error handler. In order to replace the default error handler with `bar`, I would run `options(stop = bar)` so long as `bar` has been imported.

I would like `bar` to automatically be set as the default error handler whenever I begin an R session. To that end, I put the following code in my `.Rprofile` file:

```
options(defaultPackages=c(getOption("defaultPackages"), "foo"),
        error = Bar)
```

Unfortunately, this won't work. During start up, R will first run everything in `.Rprofile` and then runs `.First.sys` in order to load the default packages. This means that `foo` will be loaded and `bar` imported after the options are set, meaning that an error will be thrown stating that `bar` could not be found.

One work around to this is to manually load `foo` by instead using the following:

```
if (require(foo))
  options(error = Bar)
```

Is this a safe solution? It seems that automatically loading `foo` immediately when starting R might cause unforeseen issues when installing a library.

Are there any other solutions besides this? The documentation on the start-up of R says that `.First.sys` is the very last thing to be run, meaning the default packages will not be loaded until after all other start-up code has been run.

Comment: Does `options(error = foo::Bar)` work?

Comment: It does, but why? It seems like `Bar` would be exported whenever the `foo` namespace is created.